# Style radio button labels inside a form

Tags: html, css

How can I style my radio button labels using  so that they stay on the same line as the search box and Locate button? I also want to style the text box value "Enter address...." Thank you!

CSS

```
   .reportText_font {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #333;    
    }
   form {
        display: inline;
      }
   #searchArea {
        margin-left:35px;
        height: 22px;
      }
```

HTML

```
<div id = "searchArea">
        <input id ="address" size="38" style="color:#333" value="Enter address (including state) or ZIP code" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"/>
        <button id="locate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Locate</button> 
        <form>
           <input type="radio" name="template" value="1" id="res" checked>Residential
            <input type="radio" name="template" value="2" id="com">Commercial
        </form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fRkc/3/

Comment: Well, how do you want to style the text box? It would also appear that your radio buttons do stay on the same line as the text box and button, but if you adjust the width of the window on your fiddle they relocate to lower lines. Is that what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Hi sorry. When I encased the input type lines with <p class="reportText_font">, it formats the text correctly but it pushes it to the next line. http://jsfiddle.net/6fRkc/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work for the radio button labels.

CSS

```
label[for=res], label[for=com]{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #333;
}


<form>
        <input type="radio" name="template" value="1" id="res" checked>
        <label for="res">Residential</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="template" value="2" id="com">
        <label for="com">Commercial</label>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is target the radio button specifically along the lines of:

```
 input[type="radio"]
```

of course you will want to be more specific as not to select every radio button. Vertically align it to the top, then apply a margin to the top to drop it down what you need. This will keep all the other text in place and only move the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `white-space: nowrap` to the selector for the outer container should get everything on the same line.

```
#searchArea {
    margin-left:35px;
    height: 22px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encase the `<input>...</input>` lines with:

```
<span class="reportText_font"></span>
```